# Problem regarding matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Establish that there cannot exist real $3$ x $3$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $ \DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
AB - BA = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0& 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $

Solution: We know $\tr (A) + \tr (B) = \tr (A+B)$ and $\tr (BA) = \tr (AB)$.

Hence $\tr(AB -BA)$ must be equal to $0$.

Is this all?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Maybe you can say, more precisely, that  the trace is a linear form on the space of $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: Wow... just wow... Never thought of it that way... @Bernard

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's all, but $\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=0$ is an essential fact here. If the field is not $\mathbb R$ but a field of characteristic $3$ instead, the matrix in question would have zero trace (because $1+1+1=0$) and it is indeed equal to $AB-BA$, where
$$
A=\pmatrix{2&0&2\\ 2&1&0\\ 1&0&2},
\quad B=\pmatrix{1&2&1\\ 0&0&2\\ 0&2&0}.
$$